# Django: function get_model with a tuple

Tags: django, model

The django function `get_model()` takes an app name and model, but I was curious as to whether you can us it with a tuple

i.e. something like

```
get_model(('app','model'))
```

Thanks, sorry if this is basic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not? it's python! Expand your tuple with `*`

`get_model(*('app', 'model'))`

Comment: Isn't that always the best? ;)

Comment: Definitely the way to do this.